# Удалить текст первого потомка не затрагивая остальных тегов

Tags: javascript, html, dom

`вот пример` https://jsfiddle.net/9hdxbjcy/
нужно убрать оценки около комментариев не затрагивая кнопки оценок (они невидимые с title Голосовать за и Голосовать против)
пробовал регулярным выражением убрать все цифры,точки и минусы

```js
var s = document.querySelectorAll('span[class="comment_rating"]');
for(i in s) s[i].innerHTML = s[i].innerHTML.replace(/[0-9(.)^-]/g, "");
```

но тогда заменяется и `class` "vote-plus" на "voteplus" и кнопки исчезают.

пробовал гуглить "delete text node without elements javascript" в google
нашёл такой пример: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/UK9xU/

он вроде работает,но я не понимаю как его исправить чтобы у меня работал без jQuery.

Comment: ой точнее тот пример на Jquery , а мне нужно без него,вот пример на чистом JS - http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/aHW9J/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно выбрать все нужные `span`

```
var s = document.querySelectorAll('span[class="comment_rating"] span');
```

Затем у каждого из выбранного удалить первую текстовую ноду

Например так:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(s, function(el) {
  el.childNodes[0].remove();
})
```

Пример в общем

```js
var s = document.querySelectorAll('span[class="comment_rating"] span');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(s, function(el) {
  el.childNodes[0].remove();
})
```

```css
div.vote-plus {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 33px;
  margin: 7px 0 0 14px;
  background: url(../images/icon_smiles.png) no-repeat 0 -40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}
div.vote-minus {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  margin: 7px 0 0;
  background: url(../images/icon_smiles.png) no-repeat -40px -40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}
div.vote-plus:hover {
  background-position: 0 0
}
div.vote-minus:hover {
  background-position: -40px 0
}
.comment_rating div.vote-plus,
.comment_rating div.vote-minus {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  background: url(../images/icon_smiles.png) no-repeat 0 -120px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}
.comment_rating div.vote-plus {
  background-position: 0 -120px
}
.comment_rating div.vote-minus {
  background-position: -40px -120px
}
.comment_rating div.vote-plus:hover {
  background-position: 0 -80px
}
.comment_rating div.vote-minus:hover {
  background-position: -40px -80px
}
span.comment_rating {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #949393;
  line-height: 40px;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<div class="comment_list_post" id="comment_list_post_2525309" creatorid="474795">
  <div id="comment11705545" class="comment" parent="2525309" timestamp="1458144862" userId="399057">
    <div class="txt" id="comment_txt_2525309_11705545">
      <div>Бог с фотошопом балуется.</div>
      <div class="comments_bottom">
        <img src="http://img1.joyreactor.cc/pics/avatar/user/399057" class="avatar" alt="Max_the_Human" /><span class="reply-link"><a href="/user/Max_the_Human" class="comment_username username_93512b8ca5c427df51aefe595acd3b9cc0ecb23653925128809f5065790262f7">Max_the_Human</a><span class="comment_date"><span class="non-localized-time" data-time="1458144862"><span class="date">16.03.2016</span>
        <span class="time">19:14</span>
        </span>
        </span><a href="javascript:" class="response">ответить</a><a href="/post/2525309#comment11705545" class="comment_link">ссылка</a>
        </span><span class="comment_rating" comment_id="11705545"> <span>3.1<div class="vote-plus" title="голосовать за" ></div>  <div class="vote-minus" title="голосовать против" ></div></span> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment_list" creatorid="399057" id='comment_list_comment_11705545'>
    <div id="comment11705563" class="comment" parent="2525309" timestamp="1458144956" userId="474795">
      <div class="txt" id="comment_txt_2525309_11705563">
        <div>Эволюция балуется.</div>
        <div class="comments_bottom">
          <img src="http://img1.joyreactor.cc/pics/avatar/user/474795" class="avatar" alt="Dalvus.." /><span class="reply-link"><a href="/user/Dalvus.." class="comment_username username_9ede21462ca67014555f7f030f9a6baff28ca53cd72613b0f5c6d32cd910c596">Dalvus..</a><span class="comment_date"><span class="non-localized-time" data-time="1458144956"><span class="date">16.03.2016</span>
          <span class="time">19:15</span>
          </span>
          </span><a href="javascript:" class="response">ответить</a><a href="/post/2525309#comment11705563" class="comment_link">ссылка</a><a href="/post/2525309#comment11705545" class="comment_link">↑</a>
          </span><span class="comment_rating" comment_id="11705563"> <span>-0.2<div class="vote-plus" title="голосовать за" ></div>  <div class="vote-minus" title="голосовать против" ></div></span> </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_list" creatorid="474795" id='comment_list_comment_11705563'></div>
  </div>
  <div id="comment11705558" class="comment" parent="2525309" timestamp="1458144928" userId="474795">
    <div class="txt" id="comment_txt_2525309_11705558">
      <div>А может 5й...</div>
      <div class="comments_bottom">
        <img src="http://img1.joyreactor.cc/pics/avatar/user/474795" class="avatar" alt="Dalvus.." /><span class="reply-link"><a href="/user/Dalvus.." class="comment_username username_9ede21462ca67014555f7f030f9a6baff28ca53cd72613b0f5c6d32cd910c596">Dalvus..</a><span class="comment_date"><span class="non-localized-time" data-time="1458144928"><span class="date">16.03.2016</span>
        <span class="time">19:15</span>
        </span>
        </span><a href="javascript:" class="response">ответить</a><a href="/post/2525309#comment11705558" class="comment_link">ссылка</a>
        </span><span class="comment_rating" comment_id="11705558"> <span>0.8<div class="vote-plus" title="голосовать за" ></div>  <div class="vote-minus" title="голосовать против" ></div></span> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment_list" creatorid="474795" id='comment_list_comment_11705558'></div>
  <div id="comment11705579" class="comment" parent="2525309" timestamp="1458145051" userId="100743">
    <div class="txt"></div>
    <div id="comment11705819" class="comment" parent="2525309" timestamp="1458146854" userId="469688">
      <div class="txt" id="comment_txt_2525309_11705819">
        <div>Зовут Karlee Hendricks, вот её инстаграм (впрочем, он закрыт) <a href="http://link.joyreactor.cc/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Flilkarls%2F" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">https://www.instagram.com/lilkarls/</a>
          <br>Для ищущих что-то похожее с, кхм, академическими интересами - вот камхора со схожими ттх <a href="http://link.joyreactor.cc/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fprofiles.myfreecams.com%2FAngelDustBaby" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">https://profiles.myfreecams.com/AngelDustBaby/</a>.
          Видеоматериал с оной легко гуглится. Эниджой.</div>
        <div class="comments_bottom">
          <img src="http://img0.joyreactor.cc/pics/avatar/user/469688" class="avatar" alt="Mistgloom" /><span class="reply-link"><a href="/user/Mistgloom" class="comment_username username_992e5007918a0f27a483b785f0c9366e0203a58ac294236370e6254046c1d941">Mistgloom</a><span class="comment_date"><span class="non-localized-time" data-time="1458146854"><span class="date">16.03.2016</span>
          <span class="time">19:47</span>
          </span>
          </span><a href="javascript:" class="response">ответить</a><a href="/post/2525309#comment11705819" class="comment_link">ссылка</a>
          </span><span class="comment_rating" comment_id="11705819"> <span>0.6<div class="vote-plus" title="голосовать за" ></div>  <div class="vote-minus" title="голосовать против" ></div></span> </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_list" creatorid="469688" id='comment_list_comment_11705819'>
      <div id="comment11705924" class="comment" parent="2525309" timestamp="1458147333" userId="469688">
        <div class="txt" id="comment_txt_2525309_11705924">
          <div>UPD
            <br>Ну или вот ещё лицекнига <a href="http://link.joyreactor.cc/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FJacelynnOfficial%2F%22" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">https://www.facebook.com/JacelynnOfficial/</a>, тут она (камхора) несколько естественней
            выглядит.
          </div>
          <div class="comments_bottom">
            <img src="http://img0.joyreactor.cc/pics/avatar/user/469688" class="avatar" alt="Mistgloom" /><span class="reply-link"><a href="/user/Mistgloom" class="comment_username username_992e5007918a0f27a483b785f0c9366e0203a58ac294236370e6254046c1d941">Mistgloom</a><span class="comment_date"><span class="non-localized-time" data-time="1458147333"><span class="date">16.03.2016</span>
            <span class="time">19:55</span>
            </span>
            </span><a href="javascript:" class="response">ответить</a><a href="/post/2525309#comment11705924" class="comment_link">ссылка</a><a href="/post/2525309#comment11705819" class="comment_link">↑</a>
            </span><span class="comment_rating" comment_id="11705924"> <span>0.0<div class="vote-plus" title="голосовать за" ></div>  <div class="vote-minus" title="голосовать против" ></div></span> </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_list" creatorid="469688" id='comment_list_comment_11705924'></div>
      <div id="comment11705966" class="comment" parent="2525309" timestamp="1458147565" userId="248304">
        <div class="txt" id="comment_txt_2525309_11705966">
          <div>https://camshowdownloads.com/PqtU1g/model/myfreecams/AngelDustBaby
            <br>ловите подборочку на вторую тян (НЕ САБЖ!!!)что ли, правда предупреждаю что все ссылки идут на кровавый upstore.net</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Код

```
var s = document.querySelectorAll('span[class="comment_rating"]>span');
for(i in s) {
    s[i].innerHTML = s[i].innerHTML.replace(/^.+?</, "<");
}
```

Пример работы тут - https://jsfiddle.net/9hdxbjcy/1/

#### Описание

Исходя из разметки рейтинга и кнопок для голосования:

```
<span class="comment_rating" comment_id="11705545">
   <span>3.1
      <div class="vote-plus" title="голосовать за"></div>
      <div class="vote-minus" title="голосовать против"></div>
   </span>
</span>
```

Суть действий - находим span, непосредственно в котором стоит рейтинг, и удаляем весь текст до первого тега (символ `<`)